# Add gradient changing to center and back

Tags: android

I need to put this like background of items in list and it works fine. What to change if I want to start and end color be the same but changing to first_color(start)->second_color(center)->first_color(end) ?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#aa0099" 
        android:endColor="#aa0099"
        android:angle="270"
     />
     <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this for center

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#aa0099" 
        android:centerColor="#9900aa"
        android:endColor="#aa0099"
        android:angle="270"
     />
     <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

as you can set the color for centerColor and also check with angle value